# Proving that it is undecidable if a Turing machine accepts a language that is its own reverse

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decision-problem

I have a Turing machine M. How can I prove that $L(M) = (L(M))^R$ is decidable by constructing a Turing machine that can do this? I know how to figure out if two DFA's accept the same language (using the symmetric difference) however I don't believe it works for Turing machines. Now I am able to design a Turing machine where, for a string w, I can determine whether or not the reverse of w is also accepted by the language. The problem is that I'm having trouble determining if the set of all strings is the same as the set of all reverse strings. If I design another TM then I feel like it's just going to infinitely loop. So how can I prove that this is decidable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision problem

> Given Turing machine $M$, is $L(M) = (L(M))^R$?

is *undecidable*. This is a simple consequence of Rice's theorem.

The property (i.e. class of Turing-recognizable languages)

$$\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{rev}} = \{ L \mid L \; \text{recognizable and } L = L^R \}$$

is non-trivial, since $\emptyset \in \mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{rev}}$ and $\{ ab \} \notin \mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{rev}}$.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear so I'm given a Turing machine M and the question is does (L(M))^R = L(M) where (L(M))^R is the reverse of each string in the language. Is it undecidable because we're working with Turing machines?

Comment: fun fact: the problem $L=L^R$ is already undecidable for context-free grammars.

Comment: If you are unhappy with Rice's theorem, here is a reduction from the acceptance problem for Turing machines.

Given an instance $\langle M,w \rangle$, build a description of the
machine $M'$ whose behaviour is

On input $x$: "

1. If $x=ba$ then *accept*
2. If $x=ab$ then simulate $M$ on $w$ and if $M$ accepts, then
*accept*, else if $M$ rejects, then *reject*
3. Otherwise, *reject*"

We have that $L(M') = (L(M'))^R$ if and only if $M$ accepts $w$.